# how to restrict validatin check on gridview button click in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have form that have some fields with `requireFieldValidation` and also `Gridview with edit and cancel button`

When I try to edit gridview it asks me for fullfill requireFieldValidation first.

I have some idea that I need to change some property to `true` to `false` in gridview but not exaclty knowing what?

Am I right? Or need some code to restrict this validation on gridview edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `CausesValidation='false'` on the edit button

Answer (score 1):

To ignore the validation rules added via ASP.NET Validation Control for the Button/LinkButton/ImageButton, set value of `CausesValidation` property to `false`. Also set [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) property for each control, it allow you to organize validation controls on a page as a set.